# Counting "Friends" in either direction in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a model where people can "Friend" each other (Friendships).  How could I query the # of people a person is both friend towards and friended by, without counting 2-way friendships twice?

Here's an example:

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 1
1 -> 3
4 -> 1
```

I'd want that to register as #1 having 3 friends

Friendships (id, person_id, friend_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select
  count(distinct(f.user_id + f.friend_id))
From
  Friends f
Where
  f.user_id = 1 or f.friend_id = 1
```

It might be more efficient to do something like this, though:

```
Select
  Count(*)
From (
  Select friend_id From Friends f Where f.user_id = 1
  Union
  Select user_id From Friends f where f.friend_id = 1
) as a
```

For getting everyone's friend count, assuming a users table too:

```
Select
  u.user_id,
  count(distinct f.user_id + f.friend_id)
From
  Users u
    Left Outer Join
  Friends f
    On u.user_id = f.user_id Or u.user_id = f.friend_id
```

Though joining using an or usually means a slow query. The other way would be:

```
Select
  u.user_id,
  count(distinct f.friend_id)
From
  Users u
    Left Outer Join (
      Select user_id, friend_id from Friends
      Union All
      Select friend_id, user_id from Friends
  ) f
    On u.user_id = f.user_id
```

You could change Union All to Union and get rid of the distinct, not sure which would be quicker.

Comment: what if the id is not '1' and something more general for all id's...?

Comment: @GregOks added a way to do all at once.

Comment: The UNION query will count bidirectional friendship twice.

Comment: @Barmar Union removes duplicates, which should take care of that if I've written it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct f1.id,count(f1.id) 
from friendships f1 
join friendships f2 on f1.person_id = f2.friend_id
Group by f1.id
```

Comment: Wouldn't this not include the f1.friend -> f2?

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, count(*)
from
  (select id, person_id as p1, friend_id as p2 from friendships
   union select id, person_id as p2, friend_id as p1 from friendships) fs
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select person_id, sum(ct) friend_count
from (select person_id, count(*) ct from friends
      group by person_id
      UNION ALL
      select f1.friend_id, count(*) ct
      from friends f1
      left join friends f2 on f1.person_id = f2.friend_id
      where f2.person_id is null
      group by f1.friend_id) u
group by person_id
```